# How to merge datasets without creating new columns

Tags: postgresql, data, carto

I am using Carto Builder and I have two datasets with exactly the same column headings but each dataset has different data under each column heading.

Is there a way to merge the data without creating a new column heading each time. I've been using the Merge Datasets function but can't find a way to avoid creating a new column each time.

[image] 
[image]

As you can see they have the same column names and I just want to merge the data below all into one whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Open any dataset (from your Dataset dashboard, instead of doing it in BUILDER) and apply the following SQL query:

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT
    the_geom,
    _end,
    ...
  FROM
    table_name1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    the_geom,
    _end,
    ...
  FROM
    table_name2)
SELECT *, row_number() over() as cartodb_id FROM data
```

You will need to replace `...` with the rest of your field names (except `cartodb_id`). Finally, after applying you would need to `Create a new dataset from query...`.